# C programming: how do you print the contents of a file after it's been dynamically allocated?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

In the program, I prompt the user to open up a file he desires. I then dynamically allocate the contents of the file into a 2D array. Then in a separate function, I'm supposed to print the contents of the file onto the screen. I don't get any errors when I run this, but the contents of the file just don't print onto the screen like what I intended it to. How do I get the contents of the file to print onto the screen? Did I dynamically allocate its contents into the array correctly?

The format of the file is something like this

> 1 0 0 0
>
> 0 0 0 1
>
> 1 1 1 1

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *get_grid(int ar[3][4]);
FILE *display_grid(int ar[3][4], FILE *fp);

int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char **ptr;
  int ar[3][4];

  fp = get_grid(ar);
  display_grid(ar, fp);
}//main ()

FILE *get_grid(int ar[3][4])
{
  FILE *fp;
  int i;
  char file[80]; 
  char **ptr;
  printf("File name: ");
  scanf("%s", file);
  fp = fopen(file, "r");
  ptr = (char **)malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    ptr[i] = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
  return fp;
}//get grid

FILE *display_grid(int ar[3][4], FILE *fp)
{
  fprintf(fp, "%s", ar);
}//display grid
```

Comment: In `get_grid` you allocate `ptr` and `ptr[i]`, but you lose track of those allocations when `get_grid` returns.  Perhaps you intended to assign to `ar`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some logical problems:

1. In `ptr[i] = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));`, the **3** should actually be **4+4**. That number is your number of columns. In each row, you have 4 digits separated by 3 spaces. That's 7 characters (or columns). You also have a trailing newline character. So that's a total of 8 columns.
2. You are not reading from the file anywhere.
3. From the comments, as William Pursell pointed out, you're allocating memory for an array local to `get_grid()`. This memory allocated does not affect your `ar[][]` in the main.
4. You said you needed to print the contents of the file onto the screen, why then would you use `fprintf(fp, "%s", ar)`? That would just output the contents back to your input file. You can just `printf()` instead.

**Solutions:**

1. Change

   `ptr[i] = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));`

   into

   `ptr[i] = (char *)malloc(8 * sizeof(char *));`
2. Inside the `for` loop in `get_grid()`, right after you allocate memory for `ptr[i]`, read the contents of the file line-by-line as follows:

   `fgets(ptr[i], sizeof(ptr[i]), fp);`
3. Now that you have read from the file, right after the above statement, update your `ar` as follows:

---

```
/* Make sure you initialize 'p' and 'j' in the beginning */
char *p = strtok(ptr[i], " ");  /* This code gets the numbers from the */
do                              /* space-delimited array you have read from the file */
{                               /* Example: */
    ar[i][j] = atoi(p);         /* ptr[i]: "0 0 0 1" */
    j++;                        /* strtok(ptr[i], " ") will yield the first '0' */
} while(p = strtok(NULL, " ")); /* strtok(NULL," ") will continue where the previous */                 
                                /* strtok() left off */
```

---

Finally, change your `display_grid()` as follows:

---

```
int i, j;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        printf("%d ", ar[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

---

With all this said, I must point out several things:

- Type-casting a `malloc` call is unnecessary in C. Read [this](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) for more information.
- A problem in your code - if your number of rows and columns changes, you'd have some trouble keeping up with those changes. I suggest you `#define` your number of rows and columns and use those definitions throughout.
- Make sure you **free your allocated memory at the end of `display_grid()`** to avoid memory leak situations.
- You have several unused variables in your code. (It annoys nitpicky people like me.)
- You do not need to go passing around your file pointer. Only `get_grid()` must have your file pointer. Of course, if your needs evolve, then ignore this statement.